# AngularDart Components Dropdown Selects selectionChange event

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart, angular-components

I'm using `material-dropdown-select` component, but I didn't find the way to trigger the event when the user changes the  selection.

(on selection change ??)

```
<material-dropdown-select class="psDropDown" dir="rtl"
                    [buttonText]="dropDownSelectLabel" 
                    [selection]="singleSelectModel" 
                    [options]="lookUpOptions"
                    ></material-dropdown-select>
```

How can I react to a selection change event

Comment: Highlighting "AngularDart dropdown select" doesn't help if you're actually using `material-dropdown-select`. You still didn't add your code to the question.

Comment: Have you tried trigger as suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to [`selectionChanges`](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/a616a05190402f9127ddadd057948f0920dbd467/lib/src/model/selection/selection_change_notifier.dart#L22) of the [selection model](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components_example/blob/master/lib/src/material_select_demo/material_select_demo.dart#L146)

Comment: I tried your suggested and it doesn't work, but `material-select` is diffrent from `material-dropdown-select` because I used `[Options]` and not `material-select-item` so I need to use event that is relevant for `material-dropdown-select`.

Comment: Do you have a sample code for it? I didn't understand how to do it.

Comment: It would be better if you posted the code that demonstrates what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: Glad to hear. . .

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from Günter I wrote this code and it works!

```
singleSelectModel.selectionChanges.listen((e)=>onChange());
```